# Counting tokens

Tags: macros, tex-core

Is it possible to count the tokens/macro parameters. For example:

```
\def\foo#1{...}
$ \foo{\alpha\beta} $ % => \somecounter = 2
```

Comment: Sorry, do you mean now tokens OR macro arguments? Both are quite different: `A{something}\beta` are 13 tokens but only 3 macro arguments.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I am sorry; I didn't know there is a difference. Tokens is what I mean. But thank you very much for showing a macro parameter counter as well!

Comment: @morbusg: One thing to note is that when TeX scans for macro arguments it does not simply take the next _n_ tokens, but obeys `{ }` etc. The TeXBook will give you a more details explanation. In short: while `{ }` groups tokens together, it doesn't represent them as one token (but as one macro argument ;-) ). However, other programming languages mostly talk about _expressions_ and allow `{ }` to group multiple expressions together while the group represents _one_ expression by itself. (Sorry if this sounds now very complicated and may not even be 100% correct)

Comment: @Martin. What I think you're getting at is that each argument of a macro is a <balanced text>, which means either a _single_ token or a set of tokens wrapped up inside `{` ... `}` (assuming normal category codes).

Comment: @morbusg. To clarify, something like `ab{cd}e` is 4 items of <balanced text> but 7 tokens. Which value do you actually want? (You might even want 5, ignoring the braces entirely.)

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I didn't even dare to dream it would be possible, but now that you mention it, I would like to ignore the braces and sub-/superscripts (`_`'s/`^`'s, not their content). Although, as this is getting more and more complicated, I am starting to think I have the wrong approach to the problem to which this question would've been a "helper function". Nevertheless, the answers have been highly enlightening, and it's breaking my heart not being able to choose more than one as an "accepted" answer.

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, that was what I meant. Thanks for explaining it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joseph Wright's solution doesn't need the additional helper macros (`\@stop` and `\cleanup@nil`):

```
\makeatletter
\def\counttokens#1{%
  \def\counttokens##1{%
    \the\numexpr\expandafter\@counttokens##1#1\@nnil\@nnil\relax
  }%
}
\counttokens{ }
\long\def\@counttokens#1{%
    \csname @\ifx#1\@nnil first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
    {0\remove@to@nnil}{1+\@counttokens}
}

\def\test{abc de\par}
\counttokens\test
\counttokens{}
```

And Martin Scharrer's solution can be made more elegant as follows. Amongst other issues, there is no need for the `\eatspace` macro.

```
\makeatletter
\def\counttokens#1{%
  \def\counttokens##1{%
    \let\tokencount\m@ne
      \def\@counttokens{\futurelet\@let@token\@@counttokens}%
      \expandafter\@counttokens##1#1\@nnil
  }%
}
\counttokens{ }
\def\@@counttokens{%
  \csname @\ifx\@let@token\@nnil first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
    \remove@to@nnil{%
        \edef\tokencount{\the\numexpr\tokencount+1}%
    \afterassignment\@counttokens
      \let\@let@token= %
    }%
}

\counttokens{A{something}\beta}
\show\tokencount

\counttokens{ 1 2 3 }
\show\tokencount
```

Comment: I've edited your answer to mark up the code. For inline snippets, this is done using backticks at each end. For longer blocks, an indent of four spaces is used, or you can use the `010101` button in the editor to mark up an existing block.

Comment: thanks for posting an improvement on my code. I'm always happy to learn more.

Comment: The `\expandafter` in `\expandafter\@counttokens##1#1\@nnil` shouldn't be there, should it? It will expand the first token of the argument, which isn't wanted.
The code runs well without it.

Comment: @Martin: The first token may be the only one and may be a macro to be expanded. Eg, `\def\test{abc de\par} \counttokens\test`. If the first token isn't expandable (such as plain text or nonactive characters), then `\expandafter` has no effect. The extra space introduced in the definition of `\counttokens` was to guide against the submission of empty argument to `\counttokens`, eg, `\counttokens{}` or `\counttokens\@empty`, both of which correctly return `0`.

Answer (score 7):

Depends on whether you want to count spaces. If you don't mind skipping spaces, then it is relatively easy. Using e-TeX, an expandable approach can be generated:

```
\catcode`\@=11\relax
\def\counttokens#1{%
  \number\numexpr\expandafter\counttokens@aux@i#1\@stop\@nil0\relax
}
\long\def\counttokens@aux@i#1{%
  \ifx#1\@stop
    \expandafter\cleanup@nil
  \else
    1 +
    \expandafter\counttokens@aux@i
  \fi
}
\long\def\cleanup@nil#1\@nil{}
\def\@stop{\@stop}
\def\test{abc de\par}
\counttokens\test
\bye
```

(This is essentially the [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3) function `\tl_elt_count:N` implemented in plain e-TeX.)

An alternative approach is not to require an expandable solution

```
\newcount\tokencount
\catcode`\@=11\relax
\def\:{\let\@sptoken= } \: %
\def\@stop{\@stop}
\def\counttokens#1{% 
  \begingroup
    \tokencount\z@
    \expandafter\counttoken@aux@i#1\@stop
}
\def\counttoken@aux@i{%
  \futurelet\@let@token\counttoken@aux@ii
}
\def\counttoken@aux@ii{%
  \ifx\@let@token\@stop
    \expandafter\counttoken@end
  \else
    \advance\tokencount\@ne
    \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\counttoken@space
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\counttoken@std
    \fi
  \fi
}
\def\:{\counttoken@space} \expandafter\def\: {%
  \futurelet\@let@token\counttoken@aux@ii
}
\long\def\counttoken@std#1{%
  \counttoken@aux@i
}
\def\counttoken@end\@stop{%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \number\tokencount
}
\def\test{abc  de\par}
\counttokens\test
\bye
```

I've not added any guard code for `&` tokens in `\halign`s, which would be needed for robustness in a real solution. (See Appendix D of *The TeXbook*, for example, to see what I mean.)

Comment: @Joseph: is it possible to avoid skipping spaces?

Comment: @Bruno. Do you mean in an expandable way? If so, the answer is 'not without LuaTeX', otherwise we'd have it in `expl3`!

Comment: @Joseph: I was thinking "non-expandable", but I guess it does not fit with your answer.

Comment: @Bruno. I've modified the answer to give some space counting. You might want to tap the minds of people on c.t.t with this one!

Comment: @Joseph: "one or more spaces count as one" because `\test` only contains one space, here (the two spaces are seen as one by TeX's mouth). On the other hand, with `\edef\test{abc\space\space de\par}`, we get `8` tokens. I still need to understand your solution, but it works!

Comment: @Bruno. Ah yes, was thinking of something else. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: @Joseph: Instead of `\def\:{\let\@sptoken= }\:`, can't you simply use `\futurelet\@sptoken{ }`? (I'm writing this comment both for showing off and for asking if this approach really yields exactly the same `\@sptoken` `:-)`, or if it has some drawback I don't see.)

Comment: @Hendrik. I just copied the definition from the LaTeX2e kernel. Your approach should also be fine.

Comment: @Joseph: I only just found your comment, thanks. Somehow I [didn't get a notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78078/155585).

Comment: @Joseph: Do you remember if you edited your comment? [Arjan thinks this might be the reason that the notification did't work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78078/possible-bug-in-comment-replies-with-trailing-dots/78085#78085).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using something like this: (updated version which counts also space-tokens)

```
\makeatletter
\newcount\tokencount
\def\counttoken#1{%
   \tokencount\z@ % set it to zero
   \def\x{\futurelet\@let@token\@counttoken}%
   \x#1\end@counttoken
}
% Unique endmarker
\def\end@counttoken{\@gobble{end@counttoken}}
% A macro which eats a space, the \@firstofone is required to
% avoid that the space in the parameter text itself is eaten:
\@firstofone{\def\eatspace} {}
% Recursive Macro => Loop
\def\@counttoken{%
   \ifx\@let@token\end@counttoken
      \let\x\relax
   \else
      \advance\tokencount by 1\relax
   \fi
   \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken
       % The space token will be eaten
       % Note that two spaces will still be combined by TeX!
       % If this is not what is wanted the catcode of space
       % must be changed beforehand, e.g. using \obeyspaces!
       \expandafter\expandafter
       \expandafter\x
       \expandafter\eatspace
   \else
       % Eat the next non-space token now, then call \x
       \afterassignment\x
       \expandafter\let\expandafter\@let@token\expandafter=%
   \fi
}
```

Test:

```
\counttoken{A{something}\beta}
\showthe\tokencount
% Prints:> 13
\counttoken{123}
\showthe\tokencount
% Prints:> 3
```

Basically the next token is `\let` to `\@let@token` and afterwards (`\afterassignment`) the token is counted and checked against the endmarker. Then the macro calls itself until the end marker is reached. Counts all tokens except of course the endmarker. You should add some grouping at the correct places, which depend on the exact way you apply the code.

**BUT**

if you really just want to count macro arguments, i.e. `A{something}B` would count as 3:

```
\newcount\argcount
\def\countargs#1{%
   \argcount\@z % set it to zero
   \@countargs#1\end@countargs
}
% Unique endmarker
%\def\end@countargs{\@gobble{end@countargs}} % doesn't really have to be defined; never executed
\def\end@@countargs{\end@countargs}
% Recursive Macro => Loop
\def\@countargs#1{%
   \def\@tempa{#1}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@end@@counttoken\else
      \advance\tokencount by 1\relax
      \expandafter\@countargs
   \fi
}
```

Comment: in your first code snippet, typos: `\@z -> \z@` and `\@end@counttoken -> \end@counttoken`. Also, spaces are skipped after a `\let`.

Comment: @Bruno: Thanks for pointing out the typos, I will fix them. I assumed the same behavior from `\let` as from `\futurelet` which doesn't skip spaces. That's why `\@ifnextchar` goes to some trouble to skip them manually.

Comment: @Bruno: I know updated the first code to also count space-tokens by using `\futurelet` instead. See also the comments in the code.

Comment: that works indeed! (and I might be able to use it for my question on a token list's head)

Answer (score 3):

Counting non-space arguments separately:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
\newvariables{count}{}{argcount,spacecount,nonspacecount}[\m@ne]
\advance\nonspacecount\@ne
\def\countargs#1{%
  \def\countargs##1{%
    \begingroup
    \def\end@countargs{\end@countargs}%
    \def\countargs@a{\futurelet\next\countargs@c}%
    \def\countargs@b####1{\countargs@a}%
    \expandafter\countargs@a##1#1\end@countargs
  }%
}
\countargs{ }
\def\countargs@c{%
  \ifxTF\next\end@countargs{%
    \edef\next{%
      \endgroup\argcount\the\argcount\relax
      \spacecount\the\spacecount\relax
      \nonspacecount\the\nonspacecount\relax
    }%
    \expandafter\next\@gobble
  }{%
    \advance\argcount\@ne
    \ifxTF\next\@sptoken{%
      \advance\spacecount\@ne
      \afterassignment\countargs@a\let\next= %
    }{%
        \advance\nonspacecount\@ne\countargs@b
    }%
  }%
}

% Test
\def\reserved@a#1{{#1#1#1A#1{something}#1\beta#1}}
\expandafter\countargs\reserved@a{ }
\edef\result{%
  \string\argcount: \the\argcount,\@space
  \string\spacecount: \the\spacecount,\@space
  \string\nonspacecount: \the\nonspacecount
}
\show\result

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Martin’s `\countargs` macro will not count spaces in the argument because leading spaces may be ignored when a macro grabs an argument. If we want to count spaces in the argument (I can’t see a need for that now but it is an interesting scenario), then the following code should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
\newvariables{count}{}{argcount,spacecount}[\m@ne]
\def\countargs#1{%
  \def\countargs##1{%
    \begingroup
    \def\end@countargs{\end@countargs}%
    \def\countargs@a{\futurelet\next\countargs@c}%
    \def\countargs@b####1{\countargs@a}%
    \expandafter\countargs@a##1#1\end@countargs
  }%
}
\countargs{ }
\def\countargs@c{%
  \ifxTF\next\end@countargs{%
    \edef\next{%
      \endgroup\argcount\the\argcount\relax
      \spacecount\the\spacecount\relax
    }%
    \expandafter\next\@gobble
  }{%
    \advance\argcount\@ne
    \ifxTF\next\@sptoken{%
      \advance\spacecount\@ne
      \afterassignment\countargs@a
     \let\next= %
    }{%
      \countargs@b
    }%
  }%
}

% Test
\def\reserved@a#1{{#1#1#1A#1{something}#1\beta#1}}
\expandafter\countargs\reserved@a{ }
\edef\result{%
  \string\argcount: \the\argcount,\@space
  \string\spacecount: \the\spacecount
}
\show\result

\end{document}
```