# Removing and storing the head of a token list/\toks

Tags: tex-core, token-lists

I am given a token list (parameter-less macro) `\myTokenList`, defined, e.g. by

```
\def\myTokenList{$(x + y)^2$, \ie, \(x^2+y^2+2xy\)}
```

and I want to split it as the first token, and the rest, obtaining the same result as

```
\def\head{$}
\def\tail{(x + y)^2$, \ie, \(x^2+y^2+2xy\)}
```

In most cases, this is easy using the `\split` macro below:

```
\def\split#1#2\EndMark{\def\head{#1}\def\tail{#2}}
\expandafter\split\myTokenList\EndMark
```

But this fails when the first token is a space. In fact, it even gobbles an arbitrary number of spaces.

Using `\futurelet` seems to help, but

- I would much prefer `\head` to be a macro which expands to exactly the token (not something let to it)
- I don't know how to just remove the first token, even after `\futurelet`-ting

Note that I have no control on the token list that I am given (braces will be treated differently): this is in the context of a generic debugging package for TeX's stomach.

Comment: See my updated answer on "Counting tokens", it applies (at least partially) also here. If you want to see other code doing something similar, I can recommend the source code of my 'tikz-timing' package. I'm doing futurelet-scanning there as well and also wanted the next token as macro content and not as token. Something which I coudn't achieve, but I found a workaround for that.

Comment: @Martin: that does seem similar to what I want. I think I have a (slow) way out: `\futurelet\next`, check the category code using `\ifcat\next\bgroup`, `\ifcat\next\egroup` etc., grab the last character of `\meaning\next` (this has the right character code), and build the right explicit character <token> (character code and catcode) using a `\lowercase` trick.

Comment: To distinguish between explicit and implicit characters, I can put append <token> to the list, and build a macro `\mytest#1<token>{...}` where `...` tests whether `#1` is empty or not. Then `\mytest\tokenList<token>` with the right amount of expansion will tell me whether the first occurence of <token> was at the start of \tokenList or not (<token> at the end just prevents runaway arguments). Does it seem realistic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach is to use `\futurelet` to tell if there is a space, then branch accordingly.

```
\catcode`\@=11\relax
\def\:{\let\@sptoken= } \: %
\long\def\firstofone#1{#1}
\def\splitter#1{%
  \let\splitter@arg#1%
  \expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\@let@token\expandafter\splitter@aux#1%
}
\def\splitter@aux{%
  \ifcat\noexpand\@let@token\@sptoken
    \def\head{ }%
    \splitter@aux@ii
  \else
    \expandafter\splitter@aux@v
  \fi
}
\def\splitter@aux@ii{%
  \expandafter\splitter@aux@iii\splitter@arg\@nil
}
\def\splitter@aux@iii{%
  \afterassignment\splitter@aux@iv
  \firstofone{\let\@let@token= }%
}
\def\splitter@aux@iv#1\@nil{%
  \def\tail{#1}%
}
\def\splitter@aux@v{%
  \expandafter\splitter@aux@vi\splitter@arg\@nil
}
\long\def\splitter@aux@vi#1#2\@nil{%
  \def\head{#1}%
  \def\tail{#2}%
}
\catcode`q=10\relax
\def\test{q\space abc}
\splitter\test
\show\head
\show\tail
\bye
```

This needs a few refinements, for example to handle empty or single-token arguments, but the general principle should be clear.

Comment: @Joseph: Thank you :)! Unfortunately, `\edef\test{\space\space abc}` will lead to `\head`=`{ }` and `\tail`=`{abc}` (no space in the tail). Is it possible to avoid that? Also, this will fail if users introduce some tokens with catcode 10 but character code different from space. For that, I will need to analyse the `\meaning` a bit more.

Comment: @Bruno. Multiple spaces are really awkward (see also my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10205/). As I've said there, I'd bring up the challenge on c.t.t. On awkward character codes, you are probably right that `\meaning` might help out, possibly combined with `\if` to test if you are dealing with a space or something else (as you know that `\meaning\splitter@arg` will start with a catcode 12 token if you have some character with catcode 10 in the original and it's not a space).

Comment: @Bruno. I'll have a crack at a better solution on the space question tomorrow.

Comment: @Bruno: You would need to change the catcode of spaces first to something else as 10 (space) to avoid that TeX is combining them. E.g. `\obeyspaces` makes them active and lets them expand to a printable space :-). The same applies to line endings.

Comment: @Martin: not quite: `\edef\twospaces{\space\space}` expands to two space tokens with catcode 10. Since my token lists arise after multiple expansions and various steps in an arbitrary LaTeX code, anything can happen.

Comment: @Joseph: I'm currently using toks rather than token lists, to avoid complications with `#`.

Comment: @Bruno: Then you should do something Joseph did in his other answer: `\ifx\@let@token\@sptoken\def\nexttoken{ }\fi` or so.

Comment: @Bruno. I've updated the answer to deal with multiple spaces. I you test this, you'll find that the 'q' does not stay as a 'q', but ends up as a space, so I think the outcome is correct.

Comment: @Bruno. If you use e-TeX, you can use `\edef\example{\unexpanded{<tokens>}}` to store `#` inside a macro. That's what we've done in `expl3`, as it cuts down on one complexity of TeX programming (or at least we feel it does).

Comment: @Joseph: I just noticed that it is difficult to make explicit space tokens other than with char code 32: in your example you start with a "blank space  ". Basically, after `\catcode\`\q=10\relax`, `\def\testA{q}`, `\def\testB{ }`, the test `\ifx\testA\testB` evaluates to true! The only way I found to produce a "blank space q" is to `\lowercase` a space with the relevant `\lccode`. --- Note that your code also converts implicit spaces into explicit ones (see my comment to Martin above). --- Thanks for the \unexpanded tip, I'll experiment with both.